# why do i get "acces denied" when trying to use file_get_contents() in a file in a bucket s3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm trying to use php functions for reading and writing files in a s3 bucket,i've tried uploading some files and it works fine , but when trying this code :

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);     
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    // Instantiate an S3 client  
    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => 'key',
            'secret' => 'secret-key',
            'region' => 'region'
        ));

    $client->registerStreamWrapper();
    $data = file_get_contents("s3://bucket_name/file.txt");
    echo $data;
```

i get this error :

```
AccessDenied Access Denied
```

plz any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: they work with the upload functions .... !!! so i guess they're right.

Comment: Missed that part, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mean that php don't have permission to read this file you can change file permission to 0777 for example.

Comment: thanks , it helps me to find the way to resolve it... :)